# opencv, link error when building a c++ project using cmake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I tried to built a c++ project by executing:  `make` but i get these errors :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcv 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcxcore   
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lml
```

and i have opencv libraries :

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
    -I/usr/include/opencv  -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core  
    -lopencv_feathures2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui     
    -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_lagecy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl 
    -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video                                  
    -lopencv_videostab
```

Comment: your makefile refers to some outdated opencv1.x version

Answer (score 1):

it means you ask the linker to link to the libraries "cv, cxcore, ml", but that the linker cannot find them. As BoBTFish  suggested; let pkg-config do this for you:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs opencv` etc...
```